# type error: projectile takes no arguments pygame

Tags: pygame, pygame-surface

class projectile(object):
    def **int**(self,x,y,radius,circle,color,facing):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius=radius
        self.color=color
        self.vel=8*facing
    def draw(win,self):

```
    pygame.draw.circle(win,self.color,(self.x ,self.y),self.radius)
```

.
.
.
.
.
for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.x < 500 and bullet.x > 0:
                   bullet.x += bullet.vel
            else:
                   bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
             if man.left:
                facing=1
             else:
                facing=1
             if len(bullets)<5:
              bullets.append( projectile (round(man.x + man.width//2),round(man.y + man.height//2),6,(0,0,0),facing) )

Comment: Can you provide a brief description and format your code to make it easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you spelled your constructor wrong. Instead of `def __int__(self,x,y,radius,circle,color,facing):` it should be `def __init__(self,x,y,radius,circle,color,facing):`.

Because it can't find your `__init__`, it uses the default instead which does not accept arguments.

Comment: @ASHMITSINGH I'm glad I could help, You should click the "green check" next to my answer to mark the question as solved.